# Detecting whether a process is idle with Java (JNA)

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I have a code:

```
int hwnd = IUser32.INSTANCE.FindWindowA(null, "Test");      
PointerByReference pid = new PointerByReference();
int threadID = IUser32.INSTANCE.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, pid);

ForegroundIdleProc proc = new ForegroundIdleProc() {

        @Override
        public int callback(int code, int wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
            /* Handle callback */
            /*Make sure you define this function first.*/
            return IUser32.INSTANCE.CallNextHookEx(hhk, code, wParam, lParam);
        }
    };

HOOK hhk = IUser32.INSTANCE.SetWindowsHookExA(IUser32.WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE, proc, null, threadID);
```

The threadId returns a correct thread id but SetWindowsHookEx returns null.
I used GetLastError to know the msg. Error code: 1428 - ERROR_HOOK_NEEDS_HMOD - Cannot set nonlocal hook without a module handle.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in regard the 3rd parameter of `SetWindowsHookEx` (counting from 1) which in your case is NULL

> A handle to the DLL containing the hook procedure pointed to by the
>   lpfn parameter. The hMod parameter must be set to NULL if the
>   dwThreadId parameter specifies a thread created by the current process
>   and if the hook procedure is within the code associated with the
>   current process.

In your case, your hooking setup process (the java one) didn't created the application/process associated w/ the 'test' window, hence you can't pass NULL to this parameter, so you must provide a handle to some DLL containing the hook procedure callback :( this means you should implement this callback logic in a *native DLL*, load it (thru JNA usage of [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and pass the returned handle to `SetWindowsHookEx`

Comment: Do you have a example? Thanks.